# Seeing intermediate deployment failures when deploying Azure function project to Azure from Visual Studio Code

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

My Azure function project now fails intermediately! I've been experiencing this for about a week.
Ex. I just deployed to my slot "dev-1" and it failed with the massage below. Then I waited about 5 minutes and tried again and it deployed!! **WTF**!!

Sometimes it fails, and sometimes it deploys with no changes made by me in between deployments!

Azure Functions(extension): v1.12.1

Visual Studio Code: v1.80.1

I'm using the Azure Functions extension in VS Code and just select my slot "dev-1" and select "deploy to slot" and then click on "deploy" in the modal that pops up. I think within the last week there were updates to both VS Code and the Azure extension. So I'm going to downgrade back to the last extension version to see if that helps.

**QUESTION**
How can I debug this issue as no errors other than what I see below are showing? The functions seem to build with no errors, of course all I'm doing is running dotnet build in the function project. Also I believe I see the project being built when I deploy as well. Maybe there is another way to debug the function project??

[image]

[image]

Here is what the output looks like, you can see at 4:04 I deployed and it worked. Then I made some small changes (commented out a line of code) and tried to deploy again at 10:54 and it failed.

[image]

Small output screen that shows the error

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the code repo?

Comment: This looks like an error related to some javascript and not related to Azure function. You can write your function code directly on Azure portal, run it and then try from Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes I know it's not an Azure function code issue, I can build, deploy it and run it just fine. Something in one of the extensions (Azure app service, Azure functions, etc) that I have installed is probably where the error is located. And probably from one of the newest versions. I tried uninstalling Azure Function extension from 1.12.1 down but that didn't help. The biggest nuance is that it deploys mostly after the 2nd try. So I deploy, it fails, then I try again and it deploys successfully! Maybe I'll just wait until the next versions and upgrade and see? I wish I knew how to debug this?

Comment: To which DC/ Region are you trying to deploy ?
Have you checked whether there are capacity restrictions ?
I have seen intermittent deployment issues in capacity constrained regions.

I would ten suggest to switch to a non-constrained regions (f.i  from west europe to Sweden Central:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/explore/global-infrastructure/geographies/#geographies

Comment: Somewhere in the West. Don't remember which one, would have to look. What do you mean capacity restrictions? Like size of the deployment?

Comment: Could also be an issue within Azure, maybe a broken rollout internally. Try switching to another region.